# Embedded video player

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Because we are dealing with Film and Video questions, I think it would be a good idea to add an embeddable video player so we can show test videos (for lenses) or asking how an effect on a video was done.

The player should support Vimeo and YouTube at least

Comment: See http://meta.avp.stackexchange.com/q/190/51

Answer (score 4):

I second the motion for Vimeo support, for what it's worth.  It's more of the "pro" site, and I haven't checked the YouTube specs in a while, but I'm pretty sure the quality cap is still much higher on Vimeo.  That makes it more appropriate for certain types of production questions.

Answer (score 2):

I also really would like vimeo embeds